# use "Class" as entity name in symfony2.1

Tags: php

I have an entity which should logically be called a "Class" (as in a class in school)

But when using

```
class Class {
```

in my code, it obviously throws an error.

because I realize this is a reserved keyword, hence the "obvious"

Is there any way around this besides giving the entity a different name?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use "class" as class name, this is a reserved word.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: i KNOW this, i am asking if there is a way to somehow get around this ..?

Comment: People often use 'Clazz' in Java

Comment: i could, it would just make more sense having it called class, it referes to for example, either, math, history, gym, etc ..

Comment: @SamJanssens "Course"? Usually a "class" in a school referes to a class as a whole and not the single topics anyway ;)

Comment: its actually a quite complicated structure, we have course-> ??class??->topic->lesson     so there is already something called a topic ..

Comment: @SamJanssens "department/subject->course->topic->lessong"? ;) I used "topic" to refer "course" here. A topic is usually more detailed, than a whole course. Just wanted to point out, that "class" is probably not the best choice...

Comment: course is our top level entity (well no, there is actually an academy entity above it, but that doesnt matter) so i am really looking for something in between a course, and the topics (every topic holds several lessons on that topic, then ever lessons holds several items, audio calls, video cals, live meetings, etc, wich again, doesnt really matter .. )